# Should I not pass a pointer by reference if I don't modify it?

Tags: c++

In the following code, should I not pass newNode by reference, since I am not modifying it?

```
void IntBinaryTree::insert(TreeNode *&nodePtr, TreeNode *&newNode)
{
    if (nodePtr == 0)
        nodePtr = newNode;
    else if (newNode->value < nodePtr->value)
        insert(nodePtr->left, newNode);
    else
        insert(nodePtr->right, newNode);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing a pointer by reference introduces an additional level of indirection.

Essentially it correspond to passing a pointer to pointer, although the compiler *can* choose to optimize that.

So it can have a cost, in stack space or register usage, and in addition time on dereferencing, on a par with and in addition to the basic cost of passing a pointer by value.

There is no reason to potentially incur that cost if you don't modify the pointer.

At higher level, the reference indicates to a reader that the pointer will potentially be modified, when it's not.

And that's ungood.

So the answer is ”no”, both for performance reasons and for clarity you should better not pass the `newNode` pointer by reference when it's guaranteed not modified.

---

The given code

```
void IntBinaryTree::insert(TreeNode *&nodePtr, TreeNode *&newNode)
{
    if (nodePtr == 0)
        nodePtr = newNode;
    else if (newNode->value < nodePtr->value)
        insert(nodePtr->left, newNode);
    else
        insert(nodePtr->right, newNode);
}
```

… could be better expressed as

```
void IntBinaryTree::insert(TreeNode*& nodePtr, TreeNode* const newNode)
{
    if (nodePtr == nullptr)
        nodePtr = newNode;
    else if (newNode->value < nodePtr->value)
        insert(nodePtr->left, newNode);
    else
        insert(nodePtr->right, newNode);
}
```

The `const` communicates to a reader that that pointer value will remain the same throughout the function body.

I think the `if`-`else` is fine even if strict application of the Don't Repeat Yourself principle would indicate a conditional expression. That's because the `if`-`else` structure here helps to reduce local complexity of the code. With a pure expression it would look more complicated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the Don't Repeat Yourself principle would indicate a conditional expression"?

Comment: @DanielGilbert: It's about the recursive calls to `insert`. Only the first argument varies. It could be specified by a `:?` conditional expression (a choice expression), which would reduce redundancy, but I think would to most readers look more complex and incomprehensible at-a-glance.

Comment: Can you please explain or link to info on why "it can have a cost, in stack space or register usage"?

Comment: When a call to the function isn't inlined and it has a formal argument of reference type, then it must be passed something that refers to the actual argument. In practice that something is the actual argument's memory address. So when the actual argument is a pointer, what's physical passed is the address of the pointer, the address of a memory location holding an address. In the code in the function body the actual argument value must then usually be retrieved from the memory location indicated by the passed address. This adds more machine code and possibly extra register usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think that passing it as a const pointer is ideal, since it helps show that it's not being modified.